# Favorite unit-testing approach for Postgresql functions?

Tags: unit-testing, postgresql, frameworks, mocking, plpgsql

I'm used to developing Java applications, but for a project I do posgresql functions. I would like to write small unittests for these functions.

I'm currently looking for a standard approach. I found pgTap and pgUnitTest, and an article from 2007: http://www.bigsmoke.us/postgresql-unit-testing/

What are you approaches to unit-testing postgresql functions? How do you mock data / separate testdata? How to isolate unit-tests? And which framework or approach is favored (I use jUnit and testNG for java)?

Comment: For generating data you can use this http://databene.org/databene-benerator.html.

Comment: upvote posting this question and having the link in here.  I'm definitely going to read it and look at pgTap.

Comment: Might be worth checking out https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded (Java), for a general Postgress testing setup. It manages a PG instance, so that you don't need to test against a real PG server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look on [pgTAP](http://pgtap.org/). It's powerful framework for postgresql unit-testing.
I prefer to use xUnit tests style, but pgTAP doesn't limit you and allows to use simple functions to write tests.